# Jasmine 'expect(...).withContext is not a function' error

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I was looking for a way to make failure messaging more descriptive in Jasmine and found this functionality https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#withContext

So I try it in my Protractor framework like this

`expect(true).withContext("something else").toBe(false);`

Run the test and get error `- Failed: expect(...).withContext is not a function`

This feature was implemented since Jasmine 3.3.0, so I checked my package.json and see `"jasmine": "^3.3.1"`, and package-lock.json has

```
"jasmine-core": {
      "version": "3.3.0",
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: you should overwrite or create new function for jasmine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just got an answer from Jasmine team on the GitHub stating

> Protractor uses jasminewd wrapper which uses Jasmine 2.x. If you want
>   to use Jasmine 3.x, you can use Protractor 6.0, that has been released
>   recently. In older versions the newest features of Jasmine, like
>   withContext function, async hooks (e.g. onSpecDone) are not available.

Besides the difference in Protractor version I found out that my grunt task runner has been using grunt-protractor-runner v5.0.0 which used protractor 5.4.2. So I had to open protractor.conf.js directly with protractor.

Comment: Protractor is officially deprecated by now. Try to move to Cypress. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5502. For unit testing I try to use jest.