# 'expect(...).withContext is not a function' error using Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, assert, withcontext

I use Protractor 7.0 and Jasemine 3.6.1, but when i use `.withContext()`, I get `Failed: expect(...).toEqual(...).withContext is not a function` error message.
I have searched the issue and the people suggest to update the Jasmine and Protractor, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jasmine 'expect(...).withContext is not a function' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55502100/jasmine-expect-withcontext-is-not-a-function-error)

Comment: your machine may have 2 different protractors: global and local. You may think you're using 7, but in fact another one may be used

Comment: No, that answer did not help me. My global and local protractor are the same - 7.0.0 @SergeyPleshakov

Comment: what about me second comment?

Comment: I said, that my global and local protractor was the same version